# How to truly turn off Tiered Compilation?

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

My local Java environment is still on

```
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I configure Jboss, I tried to turn off Tiered Compiler as Oracle suggested [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html), now there is the jvm parameters (with `-XX:-TieredCompilation`):

```
VM Arguments: -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat 
-XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:E:\serverLog\jvm.log
-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true 
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman 
-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=E:\JAVA
\JBOSS\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\log\boot.log 
-Dlogging.configuration=file:E:\JAVA\JBOSS\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0
\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

However, I still see Tiered Compilers showing up in boot.log from JBoss:

```
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
```

I wonder whether `HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers` means `-XX:-TieredCompilation` didn't take effect? Then how can I truly turn off tiered compilation?

## UPDATE

Weird thing is I add `-server` in the jvm parameter however it never show up in the jvm parameters in boot.log by Jboss.

Comment: Not sure about the compiler, but `-server` is implied for 64-bit HotSpot.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, now JDK supports `-client`, `-server`, `-tiered`. Tiered is a smart compiler can mix server and client. It looks -tiered is implied along with -server(from that jboss log).

Comment: Try adding `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and see what the effective value of the `TieredCompilation` flag is. It may be that some other setting is implicitly re-enabling it.  However - why do you want to turn it off? The performance of the server JVM is pretty lousy without it,

Comment: @skaffman Thanks I have a silly question: how can I output -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal results into a file? I have to turn Tiered Compiler off because of a Jboss performance issue https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228920?tstart=0

Comment: TieredCompilation makes things faster, not slower. Turning it off looks like a mistake. Have you tried just with `-server`?

Comment: @skaffman I tried but as  chrylis mentioned isn't it is the default setting? I set to -server but in Jboss root.log I cannot find anywhere mention -server compiler, hence this thread..

Comment: I just noticed that you're using Java 6. According to the Oracle link you quoted, tiered compilation was only introduced with Java 7, so that flag might not make any difference. You're aware that Java 6 is long past its end-of-life date, right? Even Java 7 is EOL now.

Comment: @skaffman You are right. Unfortunately this JDK setting comes with requirements so we have no liberty to change...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to verify that tiered compilation is off simply run your application with `-XX:+PrintCompilation`.

The output should look approximately like this <sup>[tested with java8]</sup>

```
 2087 1856     n 0       sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector::poll0 (native)   
20009 2146   !   4       java.io.PrintWriter::println (27 bytes)
```

The ~5th column indicates the compilation tier.

With tiered compilation off it should look like this:

```
12001  355   !         java.io.PrintWriter::write (58 bytes)
```

Note that the column indicating the tier is missing

Comment: Thank you! I found this way can effectively verify that Tiered Compiler works and -XX:-TieredCompilation does take effect. One silly question: how can I output above 'PrintCompilation' in to a file?

Comment: not sure if that'll work, but try `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions  -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=debug.log`. or simply redirect stdout/stderr.

Comment: @Dreamer There is an option `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:LogFile=./sandbox.log`